# Check n between range

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I have a little struggle here. I'm writing program in **vb.net** for UWP.

I need to set the value of `n` based upon the value of `dAB`.

A value for `dAB` is inputted by user.

- If `dAB` is less than 100 then 'n' should be 0.
- If `dAB` is between 100 and 200 than 'n' should be 1
- If `dAB` is between 200 and 300 then 'n' should be 2 and so on.

I would need to use some loop I guess but really don't know how. Thanks for help

I've wanted to use if statement but don't want to input like 1000 elsif's

```
n = 0

If dAB >= 100 Then
    n = n + 1
ElseIf dAB >= 200 Then
    n = n + 2
End If
```

Comment: No looping needed, this: `n += Math.Floor(dAB / 100)` one-liner should do.

Comment: It really worked! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem! And just in case you didn't know: `Math.Floor()` returns the closest lower integral value of a decimal (i.e. `Math.Floor(3.78) = 3` and `Math.Floor(74.23) = 74` and `Math.Floor(50.99999) = 50`).

Answer (score 0):

Making @Visual Vincent's comment a community wiki answer so the question doesn't appear in the unanswered section and to help anyone else who find this.

A single line produces the desired results

```
n = Math.Floor(dAB / 100)
```

Math.Floor() returns the closest lower integral value of a decimal

i.e. Math.Floor(3.78) = 3 and Math.Floor(74.23) = 74 and Math.Floor(50.99999) = 50

[Here is the MSDN page for Math.Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.110).aspx)